# can't set UIBarButtonItem image completion block

Tags: ios, afnetworking, uibarbuttonitem

I have very strange problem. Here what happens.

I have the following in my `.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *m_rightBtn;
```

In my `.m` file in `viewDidLoad` I'm requesting something via `AFNetworking` and in completion block based on response value do the following:

```
if(isFav) {

     self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_active.png"];

} else {

     self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_inactive.png"];

}
```

So my problem is that there is no image on `UIBarButtonItem`. `Image` not sets, but when I'm trying to set image out of the completion block everything works. Something not works inside block but I can't understand what and why, why this works out of the block?

Can somebody help me to fix this issue? P.S. I'm using XCode 5 and running application under iOS7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the completion block running on the main thread - `NSLog(@"%d", [NSThread isMainThread]);`? Is `self.m_rightBtn` a non `nil` value when you hit the completion block?

Comment: AFNetworking guarantees that the completion blocks are called on the main thread.  `self.m_rightBtn` may be `nil`, though it seems unlikely given that it's created in Interface Builder.

Comment: Please post the entire method, and all code in your view controller that relates to `self.m_rightBtn`.

Comment: Yep, completion block in main thread and self.m_rightBtn is not nil. But still not work :(

Comment: Davit, you haven't posted enough information to reproduce the issue.  Please see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

this response block is in another thread, to change visual elements you need to be in the main thread, try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     if(isFav) {
         self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_active.png"];
     } else {
         self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_inactive.png"];
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combining the previous answers:

```
[favoritesOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *favoritesOperation, id responseObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        ....

        if(isFav) {
            self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_active.png"];
        } else {
            self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_inactive.png"];
        }
    });
}];
```

You could also use the [performSelectorOnMainThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) method

Comment: This is probably incorrect, given that AFNetworking guarantees that the completion blocks are called on the main thread.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is a problem with the outlets, what happens if you move all the code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear ?